# Name for the transformation into an accelerated frame?

Tags: general-relativity, rotational-dynamics, symmetry, acceleration, lie-algebra

A transformation into a frame that looks at an experiment from a rotated perspective is called a **rotation**.

A transformation into a frame that moves with a different constant velocity is called a **boost**.

**What is the name for a transformations that transformes some observers description into a frame that is accelerated relative to the first observer?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Walker_transport